# Tkinter canvas text update in a nested loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to populate text within a canvas using a nested for loop.
The intention is to list the items with set spacing similar to table.
The Canvas shows only the 1st row of values. It doesn't output the next row.
The print(cell) debug shows the cell variable updates properly.

```
canv_1 = tk.Canvas(master=root, bg='ffffff')
canv_1 .configure( height = 152, width=365)
dv= ['7%',  '5.1%', '2.1%']
summary =['N', 'Y', 'Y']

data =[summary, dv ]
x1, y1=  (180,35)
for row1 in data:
    for cell in row1 :
        print(cell)  # shell output prints correctly
        canv_1.create_text(x1, y1, fill='blue', text=cell,  anchor='ne')
        x1+=90
    y1+= 30
```

Comment: The second row is placed outside the viewable area as x1 is not reset to 180.

Comment: @acw1688 thanks. moving `x1=180` outside the inner loop, fixed the problem